# Laravel Homestead.test error 404 not found

Tags: php, laravel, framework

Estoy siguiendo un curso en YouTube de Laravel para aprenderlo y en el primer proyecto de practica me salía todo bien, pero ahora sin embargo al crear el segundo simplemente no funciona y no se porque. Lo único que hice fue crear el proyecto desde la consola de Git Bash con
composer globar require "laravel/installer" y después laravel new Laravel_2

[image: Homestead yalm]

[image: Archivo hosts de windows]

No se muy bien cual puede ser el problema.

Comment: estoy siguiendo el mismo curso mencionado anteriormente pero al querewr ejecutar homestead.test me sale el error 404 not found. estoy llamando a un controlador creado con el comando php artisan make:controller --resource Ejemplo3Controller y ya lo direccione en el archivo de rutas por Route::resource('posts',Ejemplo3Controller::class); pero me sale el error 404 not found cual sera mi error?

Answer (score 0):

me paso lo mismo; En el git bash coloca el comando "vagrant reload --provision" con esto debe de solucionarse tu problema.
Saludos,